# Spring RESTful service returns 500 internal server error

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm posting to a Spring REST endpoint using angularjs $http service. It's quite straight forward and it works as expected but the end-point is returning status code 500 internal error. But at the server side, it doesn't show any error and exception. I'm sending post request as follow

```
$http.post('../bookmarks/add',data,{
        cache:false,
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest:function(data){
            if(data===undefined)
                return data;

            return $.param(data);
        },
        responseType:'json'
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $('.add-form').hide();
        console.log(data);
        callback(data,'success');
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log(status);
        if(status==500)
            callback('Server error! Try again later.','error');
    });
```

I am able to send post request. My REST handler is as follow. It invokes a service to persist an object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","application/json", "text/plain", "*/*"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Bookmark saveBookmarks(@RequestParam("caption") String caption,@RequestParam("bookmarkUrl") String bookmarkUrl,
        @RequestParam(value="tags",required=false) String tags,@RequestParam(value="category", required=false) String category){
    System.out.println(caption+"-"+tags+"-"+category);

    //calling service and persisting the object
    Bookmark bookmark= bookmakService.saveBookmark(
            binder.getNewBookmark(caption,bookmarkUrl, dateGen.getToday(), category, tags)
            ,getUserIDFromSession());

    System.out.println(bookmark);
    return bookmark;
}
```

The above handler works as expected. The object is persisted. But the browser console shows 500 internal server error and the server doesn't log any error and exception. Everything looks straight forward. I don't know why the client is getting the 500 error. I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't lie within your server configuration?

Comment: @JohannesH.Thanks for your reply. The other REST controllers are working fine. I think the problem occurs while Jackson is trying to convert the object to JSON. Just my opnion. But the server doesn't show any error. Hard to trace.

Comment: Can you try setting logger level to trace for following package? "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc"

Comment: I've got the solution. The Bookmark object has User object. I set the user object null and it works fine. But the bookmark json object graph has still user which is now null. What should I do when I don't want the user in json object graph?

Comment: I have a similar problem and am trying to figure out how to get useful logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Jackson that ignore a property with @JsonIgnore.

```
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

Here there is a tutorial about 5 ways to ignore properties in serializing Json

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependecy in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Was facing the same issue as the return type cannot be bind with the MediaType of Class Bookmark. Ad

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, but a different cause. The problem arises if you can get the object from the database, but the json serialization fails.

For me it was due to a null value on a private **D**ouble type, but my public getter returned a **d**ouble primitive type. When the serializer tried to serialize the object, this probably returned a null-pointer-exception, but it was nowhere logged and there was no stacktrace.